# apache sqoop 1.4.4 development environment setup in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, ant, sqoop

I am trying to setup sqoop development environment in eclipse but, I do not see any instructions for sqoop 1.4.4.

I tried downloading the source from the SVN repo.

Installed ant and tried compiling the source code. But i want to set the project in eclipse.

I also tried creating a maven project under eclipse but it is giving the error

Missing artifact org.apache.sqoop:sqoop:jar:1.4.4

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used the maven dependency to resolve the above issue

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
<artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
<version>1.4.4</version>
<classifier>hadoop23</classifier>
```

I still want the ant related development setup. Please let me know.